# SharePoint Master Page Border

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

[image]

We have deployed a new master page to 2010 and our developer has left the position. Now management has given me a chance to learn development.

We had a Issue When I try to decrease the width and Size of top global navigation. The master Page is showing in veered view as shown in Fig. What to do to keep master-page Constant and increase auto?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: What code do you need to show!!

Comment: The code you used to change the size of the navigation.

Comment: I have change the code to this.GlobalNavMenu div ul > li.static {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3E64AA 0%, #193966 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 2px solid #193966;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    width: auto;
}

Comment: I saw your other question regarding creating a wsp branding package.  I'm going to assume that you did this in Visual Studio then.  Unfortunately, my HTML/CSS is rather horrible to begin with, and I don't have experience creating master pages with Visual Studio.  Try including that code in your answer, with formatting.  It'll help those with the experience/knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have too many columns in a view, which expands beyond the original width of the body. This is common among OOTB lists where multiple columns are within a view. There are many possible fixes to this problem.

- Set a min-width of 's4-bodyContainer' to a higher value
- Run a jQuery/JS script to make adjustments to the width when SP is done rendering the table.

Using the above mentioned second approach, you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fixWidth, "sp.js");
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    fixWidth();
});

function fixWidth(){
    //Elements with the potential to be too wide.
    //Make adjustments to below line based on your structure.
    elements = $(".ms-bodyareacell > div > table, .main-container > div > table, #layoutsTable");
    //#layoutsTable for Wiki Pages

    leftPanelWidth = $("#s4-leftpanel").width();
    //For each Elements
    $(elements).each(function(){
        //if it’s wider than the side width
        window.console && console.log('Width: ' + $(this).width());
        if($(this).width() > ($("#s4-bodyContainer").width() - leftPanelWidth ))
        {
            //Calculate the new width taking the left nav into account
            newWidth = leftPanelWidth + $(this).width();
            //Set the width!
            $("#s4-bodyContainer > div").attr("style","width:" + newWidth +"px");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Should also mention the easiest fix is to just to remove a column or two from the view. Many of the OOTB columns are always blank, anyway.

Comment: Its not a list ...When I try to upload the masterpage and page layouts I am seeing that Error ....Sorry to Ask I am new to development!!where do in need to Set a min-width of s4-dodyContainer and how run the jquery /jsscript and where Plse Plse help me out in this

Comment: You'd need to edit the CSS and/or JavaScript file referenced from your master page. Look up for how to apply custom master page in SharePoint. Again, there are many ways to include your JS and CSS file.